# How to break redirect loop in htaccess and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site and I want to add a music player to it in a way that music is not interrupted, and visitors can browse the website while listening continuously to the music

I added two iframes: The first loads his website, while the other one loads the music player. Then I put both in a wrapper called home.php and added the following rule to .htaccess file:

`DirectoryIndex home.php`

So the wrapper would load instead of index.php from Wordpress. The code of home.php is as follows:

```
 <iframe class="miMarco" src="index.php"></iframe>
 <iframe src="audio/index.php" frameborder="0" width="230" height="70"></iframe>
```

And that's all I've changed.

The complete .htaccess looks like this:

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default 
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
DirectoryIndex home.php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The problem arises when I go to the website, and home.php loads as the index, and then it enters a redirect loop because loads  the music player on and on, and never loads the wordpress site.

Any ideas why is this happening? Is this an .htaccess issue or a wordpress issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make it so neither `home.php` nor `audio` is being handled by wordpress. You can exclude then like the `index.php` is being excluded:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^audio - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already tried that out and it is not working. 

I even tried to replace the DirectoryIndex for an html file called splash.

Then add the instruction:

`DirectoryIndex splash.html`

and splash screen only contained a link to "home.php" (the wrapper with the two iframes) but it didn't work.

Instead, home.php was showing the music player, and the link "Click Here"

even though my iframe looks like this:

`<iframe src="index.php"></iframe>"`

In order words: home.php is loading: splash.html and audio/index.php instead of loading index.php and audio/index.php

Comment: @AlanChavez have you tried removing the `DirectoryIndex` line altogether and adding `RewriteRule ^$ /home.php [L]` above your current wordpress rules?

Comment: yes I have tried that as well, and still can't get it to work as expected.

Comment: Weird thing is, that if I call my wrapper directly:
www.misite.com/home.php
It works!
If I add the line
`DirectoryIndex home.php` is when it enters a loop and loads the music player over and over.